# !ClrStack -a call in ASP.NET MVC application shows <NO DATA>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, windbg

When attaching WinDbg to my ASP.NET MVC app and calling `!ClrStack -a` when an exception has occurred, I'm seeing no locals or params values. All I see is `<NO DATA>` appear.

Why is this happening? What settings in my project can I check?

I appreciate I can see the objects in quesiton via a `!dso` call and finding the objects I'm interesting in the output, but that's not a good solution for me, since I need to know exactly the objects being passed into a specific function - I don't want to spend ages picking eah object address and doing a `!do` on them.

The app is built in `DEBUG` mode. When viewing a stack, all the methods and types appear in the output, so I'm assuming there is no issue with symbols, though I'm willing to try any commands necessary to re-sync or update the symbols if required.

The CPU architecture is `ANY CPU` and we are running Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit.

I tried using SOSEX's `!mk` `!mframe` and `!mdv` commands, to list param and locals, but they show `<UNAVAILABLE>`.

EDIT:

Here is an example of the type of output I'm seeing:

[image: Sample clrstack output with no data appearing]

Comment: Related: [Locals and parameters show <no data>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543365/why-locals-and-parameters-show-no-data-on-the-stackframe-when-using-sos-dll-to-d) and [!clrstack -p not giving values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518588/clrstack-p-not-giving-the-values-of-the-parameters-for-the-methods-in-the-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

This happens for code optimized by the JIT compiler (your case) or release builds (by the compiler).

> What settings in my project can I check?

Always check the symbol path and add Microsoft symbols if not done yet.

```
.symfix c:\debug\symbols
.reload
```

Next, check if WinDbg can find the symbols of your application using `lm`. It should show "private pdb symbols". If not, run

```
.sympath+ <path to your PDBs>
```

Other than that, [SOSEX](http://www.stevestechspot.com/) makes your life easier. Try the following:

```
!mk; *** Managed stack
!mframe <frame>; *** Switch to frame
!mdv; *** Dump values - This will at least give you the type
!mdv <frame>; *** Same as before but include !mframe
!mdso; *** Similar to !dso
```

Comment: I updated my question to inform about my attempt at using SOSEX. I will try the `.symfix` command when I'm back in the office tomorrow. Cheers for that.

Comment: @JasonEvans: also check the output of `lm`. Add a `.sympath+ <your PDBs>` if it says something else than "private PDB symbols". I also added this to my answer.

Comment: I tan `lm` and saw the symbols for my code were `(deferred)`. I read [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069220/windbg-lm-what-does-deferred-mean) but I'm stuck. Can you force WinDbg to load the symbols, as in don't be lazy loading them?

Comment: Ahh OK. I just ran `.reload /f` to force symbol loading. I'll see if that makes a difference when it's finished.

Comment: @JasonEvans: I have better experiences with `ld *` to load symbols of all modules. IMHO, `.reload /f` still only reloads those which have already been loaded.

Comment: I will try `ld *` tomorrow. Cheers for that. Learning a lot through these comments/answers. Great stuff :)

Comment: Sorry for delay. I tried `ld *` and then `!ClrStack -a`, still getting `<no data>` appearing in the output. This is odd. I must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: @JasonEvans: maybe it's just the optimization and you can't do anything about it. Can you share the dump so that I could try it? If I can get the information, I'll send you a full log with all commands to reproduce.